# SDL_init() is causing c file to output nothing

Tags: c, sdl

I have the following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <SDL/SDL_thread.h>

#ifdef __MINGW32__
#undef main
#endif

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf ("Kishore\n");

    if (SDL_Init (SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_AUDIO | SDL_INIT_TIMER))
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "SDL: could not able to initialize SDL : %s", SDL_GetError());
        exit (1);
    }
}
```

Able to compile without any issues. But, when i ran the executable it is not giving any output.
gcc command used :

```
gcc -lSDL test.c -o test.exe
```

Am I missing anything.

Comment: If doesn't even print the string `"Kishore\n"`? If you remove the `if` statement, and only have the `printf`, does it work then?

Comment: Your code, on my system, without any modifications, works just fine.  It prins "Kishore" and exits without errors.

Comment: Note: General rule of linking: if `A` uses symbols from `B`, `B` should come after `A`. In your case, since you use symbols from `libSDL.a`, you should write `-lSDL` **after** `test.c`. I don't know why gcc didn't complain in your example, but sooner or later you are going to run into an issue with this.

Comment: @Joachim - Without any SDL function calls it works perfectly.

Comment: @Shahbaz - I even tried compiled as you suggested, but still I dont see output.

Comment: @KishoreRelangi, I know, I was saying that so you would no when you run into an issue later. In your case, if I remember correctly, SDL redirects `stdout` to `stdout.txt` have you checked to see if that file exists after you run your program?

Answer (score 3):

Windows command-line programs use the `main` entry point and output the `stdout` and `stderr` file handles (via the printf statements) to the console window. Windows GUI programs use the `WinMain` entry point and does not set up the `stdout` and `stderr` file handles to go to a console window (as they do not initialize a console window to output to), which is why you do not see the output from the `printf` statements.

POSIX (Linux/Solaris/BSD/...) use the `main` entry point for both console and GUI applications and set up `stdout` and `stderr` correctly so they appear in a terminal/console window.

SDL is a cross-platform API that simplifies graphical programs, so on Windows it is using the `WinMain` entry point so it can create a window where the graphics are displayed without a console window appearing behind it. SDLs `WinMain` calls the `main` function so you can use the `main` entry point on all platforms.

In the past, I have found:

```
test.exe | cat
```

to work, but YMMV.

Answer (score 3):

Everything you write to `stdout` and `stderr` is redirected into the files `stdout.txt` and `stderr.txt` respectively, where the exe resides.

To avoid this redirecting behaviour you have to include the following two lines *after* the call to SDL_Init.

```
freopen( "CON", "w", stdout );
freopen( "CON", "w", stderr );
```

If this is not working you can check the [SDL FAQs](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/FAQ_Console), there are more instructions.